# Linq to xml [Where node exists in one file and not in another file]

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I need assistance in retrieving the element country and Its value 1 in the first file and element Name and Its value XYZ in the second file.

I am taking Input from app.config and i have stored both the files is C:\Test\ and the file are.

Sample.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<env:Contentname xmlns:env="http://data.schemas" xmlns="http://2013-02-01/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Body>
       <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Yellow">
         </env:Data>
       </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Red">
           <Status xmlns="http://2010-10-10/">
             <Id >39681</Id>
             <Name>Published</Name>
           </Status>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
        <env:Data xsi:type="green">
          <Document>
            <country>1</country>   
          </Document>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>
  </env:Body>
</env:Contentname>
```

and My 2nd file is Sample1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<env:Contentname xmlns:env="http://data.schemas" xmlns="http://2013-02-01/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <env:Body>
       <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Yellow">
         </env:Data>
       </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
         <env:Data xsi:type="Red">
           <Status xmlns="http://2010-10-10/">
             <Id >39681</Id>
             <Name>Published</Name>
           </Status>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>

      <env:Content action="Hello">
        <env:Data xsi:type="green">
          <Document>
            <Name>XYZ</Name>   
          </Document>
        </env:Data>
      </env:Content>
  </env:Body>
</env:Contentname>
```

I Tried This,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;

namespace LinEx
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        String ReadFile = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Check"];

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(ReadFile);

        FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.xml");
        foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
        {
            XElement root = XElement.Load(fi.FullName);
            XNamespace aw = "http://data.schemas";
            XNamespace kw = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
            XNamespace ns = "http://2013-02-01/";


            var result = from x in root.Descendants(aw + "Content")
                         where (string)x.Attribute("action") == "Hello"
                         from y in x.Descendants(aw + "Data")
                         where (string)y.Attribute(kw + "type") == "green"
                         select new
                         {
                             Firstel = y.Element(ns + "Document").Element(ns + "country").Value,
                             Secondel=y.Element(ns+"Document").Element(ns+"Name").Value,
                         };

            foreach (var item in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Country value={0}", item.Firstel);
                Console.WriteLine("Name value={0}", item.Secondel);
            } 
        }   
        Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But I am getting error(Object reference not set to an instance of an object).Kindly help me with this and Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the desired output? Do you want to repair the XML by joining them together or what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Name element is not present in the first file and and country element is not present in the second file then also i am getting Country Value=  and  Name value=  and if it is not there means i should not want those value also and how can i achieve that??

Comment: @Thomas Lindvall:I want the output like Country value=1 and Name value=XYZ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First Solution** (with xPath) :
You will have to adjust namespaces and mix my code with yours, but the idea is there :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XElement file1 = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
        <Contentname>
            <Body>
                <Content action='Hello'>
                    <Data type='Yellow'>
                    </Data>
                </Content>

                <Content action='Hello'>
                    <Data type='Red'>
                    <Status xmlns='http://2010-10-10/'>
                        <Id >39681</Id>
                        <Name>Published</Name>
                    </Status>
                </Data>
                </Content>

                <Content action='Hello'>
                <Data type='green'>
                    <Document>
                    <country>1</country>   
                    </Document>
                </Data>
                </Content>
            </Body>
        </Contentname>");
    XElement file2 = XElement.Parse(@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 
        <Contentname>
            <Body>
                <Content action='Hello'>
                    <Data type='Yellow'>
                    </Data>
                </Content>

                <Content action='Hello'>
                    <Data type='Red'>
                    <Status xmlns='http://2010-10-10/'>
                        <Id >39681</Id>
                        <Name>Published</Name>
                    </Status>
                </Data>
                </Content>

                <Content action='Hello'>
                <Data type='green'>
                    <Document>
                    <Name>XYZ</Name>   
                    </Document>
                </Data>
                </Content>
            </Body>
        </Contentname>");


    List<XElement> roots = new List<XElement> {file1, file2};
    foreach (var root in roots)
    {

        var nodesCountry = root.XPathSelectElements("Body/Content[@action='Hello']/Data[@type='green']/Document/country");
        var nodesName = root.XPathSelectElements("Body/Content[@action='Hello']/Data[@type='green']/Document/Name");


        foreach (var item in nodesName)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Name value={0}", item.Value );
        }
        foreach (var item in nodesCountry)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Country value={0}", item.Value);
        }
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

**Second solution** (with the solution of @har07, less clean) :

```
select new
 {
     Firstel = (string)y.Element(ns + "Document").Element(ns+"country"),
     Secondel = (string)y.Element(ns+"Document").Element(ns+"Name"),
 };

foreach (var item in result){
        if(item.Firstel!=string.empty)
            Console.WriteLine("Country value={0}", item.Firstel);
        if(item.Secondel!=string.empty)
            Console.WriteLine("Name value={0}", item.Secondel);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following part, cast the `XElement` to `string` instead of acessing `Value` property :

```
select new
 {
     Firstel = (string)y.Element(ns + "Document").Element(ns+"country"),
     Secondel = (string)y.Element(ns+"Document").Element(ns+"Name"),
 };
```

That will avoid "Null reference" exception in the case when either `<country>` element or `<Name>` element doesn't exists in the XML document.

Comment: :Thanks;Yes i got the output and but m getting output like Country value=1
Name value=
Country value=
Name value=XYZ  and How can Remove those empty value??